# Can't run program in debugger?

Tags: debugging, gdb

I was trying to use gdb on a program earlier on a Linux 64-bit machine, and I ran gdb bomb (that's the program name), and within gdb, I simply typed in ran. It came back with the error `/bin/bash: /home/imicrothinking/ics11302016004/lab2/bomb: No such file or directory During startup program exited with code 127.`

I've dug around the net for a bit, and suggestions I've heard so far led to no concrete solutions, here's what I'm sure of so far:

1. I'm logged on as a root level user.
2. I haven't gone to the wrong directory.
3. The executable file definitely exists.

I'd welcome all suggestions.

Comment: Double check that the file exists in the path given in he error message. "No such file or directory" means what it says.

Comment: You probable need to type `gdb ./bomb` rather than just `gdb bomb`.

Comment: @JoniSalonen It definitely exists, last time I checked!

Comment: @PaulR Tried that as well, to no avail...

Comment: @imicrothinking Does your program run outside `gdb`, e.g. `./bomb` (at the shell prompt)?

Comment: @EmployedRussian No...I simply ran it within gdb after typing in gdb ./bomb...

Comment: @imicrothinking If you get the same problem outside GDB, then the problem has *nothing* to do with GDB. I have a feeling that your "No" answers some other question, and not the question I asked: "does your program run if you invoke it outside GDB?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programm exists with file not found even though the file exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899074/programm-exists-with-file-not-found-even-though-the-file-exists)

Answer (score 0):

maybe gdb cann't find your shell. so set the env var SHELL to your shell.
eg: export SHELL=/bin/bash

ref : http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/gdb-giving-wierd-error-169299/