# Program exists with file not found even though the file exists

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb, binaryfiles

I am trying to solve the binary bomb given in [this](http://opensecuritytraining.info/IntroX86.html) course. You can download the bomb itself [here](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/public/1e/bomb.tar)
When I try to start the bomb (in the terminal or in gdb)
it exists mith code 127 respectively file not found.
But since I can set permissions on the file, copy it ...
I'm pretty sure that it exists.

Well even if I open the binary in gdb and set breakpoints to main, _init and _start
it still exits before the breakpoints get hit.

So what is the reason for this and how can I solve this problem since I really want to defuse this bomb. I also don't think that this is part of the excercise, because I found solutions for this bomb and read the first step and there nothing is said about this problem.

PS: I know that this question has been asked before (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10451173/1937231)), but since the author doesn't reply and the question isn't solved I decided to ask again.

Comment: Without providing any actual details on what you've done (i.e. the command line, a gdb trace, etc) nobody can help you.

Comment: @Dave Can you isolate the issue with a few snippets of code?

Comment: Well the point is, that I don't have any code, because it's a binary bomb. Therefore no code is given. You can download the binary here: http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/public/1e/bomb.tar . I simply started it by calling `./bomb` and `gdb ./bomb` and then run. (Of course after unpacking it and setting the permissions to make it executable.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bomb` executable is dynamically linked, and requires `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` in order to run.

That file probably doesn't exist on your system (which must be running `Linux/x86_64`).

You may need to `apt-get install libc6-i386`, or something similar.

Comment: Possible hint for you, Dave. I just downloaded "bomb" (not the kind NSA is interested in, relax guys) and got the same error. (I'm real new to this system and haven't installed those files myself) However, Agner Fog's "objconv" will disassemble it - http://www.agner.org/optimize I think you might find it helpful.

Comment: You are right. Thank you very much. For everyone else who is looking for the exact package name, on Debian it is `libc6-i386`.

Comment: @FrankKotler Thank you also. I will try t. But first I will try to get used to objdump and so on ;-)